# Which desktop is installed by default?

Tags: 13.04, gui

I just installed 13.04 Desktop version... which GUI was installed??  Is this Gnome?  How do I identify which one it is?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer.

The default Desktop Environment that installed with Ubuntu is [Unity](http://unity.ubuntu.com/).  Unity as I said, is the default desktop environment used in Ubuntu. It is compatible with the GTK platform used by Gnome. It was designed to be used for netbooks, but is developed by Canonical to be useful on all types of devices.

But there are a few desktop environments that you can install.  XFCD, LXDE. KDE, Gnome. and others.

Comment: Thanks much!  I'm looking into a MP3 Manager type of program (ala Zune, iTunes, etc) and wanted to make sure I install the correct thing!

Comment: hm.. try rhythmbox or banshee. p.s. you have rhythmbox installed already.

Comment: geoh-- thanks for replying...  I've tried using rhythmbox to play a simple MP3 (audio podcast) that I downloaded, and it just wouldn't play it for some reason.  I'm sure I'm probably doing something wrong, but I downloaded VLC and it played without a problem.  Thanks!